# Genfromtxt does not return column names

Tags: numpy, genfromtxt

I want to convert a csv into a numpy array. The first row of the csv file contains the names / titles of the columns. But when I use `genfromtxt` with the `names` parameter set to `true` I still receive only a normal numpy array with a lot of `NaN` values. What did I forget?

```
numpy.genfromtxt("test.csv", names=True, delimiter=",")
array([[ NaN,  64.,  11., ...,  NaN,  NaN,  NaN],
       [ NaN,  64.,  11., ...,  NaN,  NaN,  NaN],
       [ NaN,  64.,  11., ...,  NaN,  NaN,  NaN],
       ..., 
       [ NaN,  64.,  11., ...,  NaN,  NaN,  NaN],
       [ NaN,  64.,  11., ...,  NaN,  NaN,  NaN],
       [ NaN,  64.,   5., ...,  NaN,  NaN,  NaN]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `dtype` to `None`:

`numpy.genfromtxt("test.csv", names=True, delimiter=",", dtype=None)`